# What's the $\frac{1}{2}\bigg(e+\frac{1}{e}\bigg)$ appearing in context of Bernoulli r.v.s.?

Tags: probability-distributions, martingales

What's the $\frac{1}{2}\bigg(e+\frac{1}{e}\bigg)$ I encountered in context of martingales of Bernoulli r.v.s.?

Such as:

$\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2, ...$

i.d. Bernoulli r.v.s.

Let $M_0=1$ and $M_n = e^{\epsilon_1+...+\epsilon_n-cn}$ s.t. $\mathbb{E}(e^{\epsilon_1-c})=1$ with $c=\log\bigg( \frac{e+\frac{1}{e}}{2}\bigg)$.

I.e. where does this quantity come from?

Comment: "s.t. $\mathbb{E}(e^{\epsilon_1-c})$..." are you missing an "$=$ something"?

Comment: This question is missing a lot of information.

Comment: Also, notice that if $X\sim \text{Bernoulli}(1/2)$ then $\mathbb{E}[e^X]=\frac{1}{2}\cdot e^1 + \frac{1}{2}\cdot e^{-1} = \frac{1}{2}\left(e+\frac{1}{e}\right)$.